# Linnworks Macro - How to update order item title with .Net SDK

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to update the order item title in an order using .Net SDK.

Fetching orders with `GetOrdersById` method.

```
List<OrderDetails> orders =  Api.Orders.GetOrdersById(orderIds.ToList());
```

Then I'm iterating over order and related order items and updating order item title like below.

```
 foreach (var orderDetail in new List<OrderDetails> {orderDetails})
        {
          
            foreach (var orderItem in orderDetail.Items.Where(x => x.IsService == false).ToList())
            {
                
               orderItem.Title += " " + "additional custom info";
               orderItem.ChannelTitle += " " + "additional custom info";
                        
               var result = Api.Orders.UpdateOrderItem(orderDetail.OrderId, orderItem,
                            orderDetail.FulfilmentLocationId,
                            orderDetail.GeneralInfo.Source, orderDetail.GeneralInfo.SubSource);
                  
            }
        }
```

After I make this update I cannot see any change on order items. Is there another way to update the order on SDK?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Linnworks API, but you should probably start by checking what you have in the variable `result`.

Comment: Yes I checked the result and also fetched the same order again but nothing changed. And also there is no change on Linnworks UI.

Answer (score 0):

I remember wanting to do this some years ago with the .NET SDK, and was told that item titles cannot be amended via the API.  I believe the intent is that the title should always match the StockItem's title that the item relates to.  This was quite annoying to us, we ended up adding a new Service OrderItem to the order with the text we needed.

This increases the item count on the order, which can confuse Rules Engine rules that try to refer to the number of items in the order, there's no way to tell it to ignore items with `isService=true`.

```
string title = "Some new title here";
Guid fulfilmentCenter = Guid.Empty;
UpdateOrderItemResult res = Api.Orders.AddOrderService(
    order.OrderId, title, 0, 0, fulfilmentCenter);
```

In this way, staff will see the original ordered item, e.g. "Shoes" and a second item on the order with important information about the shoes, e.g. "Shoes size Big colour Blue".

In our case the problem was that key information about an item from the sales platform comes over as Attributes on the item, which are visible in the Orders screen but are not included on printed manifests etc about the order, so when our staff came to pick the item they didn't know what attributes it had.  Quite a weird oversight that Linnworks don't seem interested in fixing.  Pretty sure I created a feature request on their website but cannot find it now.